# How to implement hit counter for online video

Tags: php, android, apache, video, counter

I have placed a video file (mp4) on a Apache server which will be accessed from a Android Application. I need to know how many times did the video have been viewed. The solutions I can think of are

1. View the Apache logs. But I have very limited access to them.
2. Call a PHP file then redirect to video file.

Any other better solutions apart from above two?

Answer (score 0):

The third option is to have a PHP file which will register the download and then deliver the file by reading it and sending it to the client.

(See http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/download-counter-in-php-using-htaccess/)

Performance-wise this is somewhat worse than either the logs / redirect methods, but it is the most reliable, as the only way a client can access the file is via the PHP script. Furthermore, you can do this without any access to logs (it is Apache-independent). You also have more control (e.g. you can count download only once per IP), but then again, the other methods allow that too, with some modifications. I am not sure if there is any other way to do it effectively besides the two you've listed and the one I suggest, maybe there is a way with PHP / Apache extensions, I am just not aware of it.

So either go with the redirect or this.